# } Expected in ForEach Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using the following code to show items in a list.I get this exception. Please advice

```
                         <div>
                            {this.showdropdown ?
                                <div className="popout-wrapper content-popout fixed-popout left show">
                                    <div className="popout-link-holder">
                                        {
                                            this.links.forEach(function (value) {
                                                <a href="#" title={value} className="link normal">value</a>
                                            });
                                        }
                                 </div>
                                </div>
                                : null}
                        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach` and remove the semi-colon (it's an expression, not a statement). You also need to `return` the `<a />`. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component

Comment: @ChrisG If i do that i get this error `void is not assignable to reactNode`

Comment: You are not returning the links. Put a return before <a></a> and it will be part of the react DOM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put your code in [prettier playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAeAJgSwG4D4A6UABCaWeRZcDABaYDOAdPTRAO7oBOEADuu8QBkgohhxEwAGwCG9egDlpAWzgBefCB68IAVxgBaNp2k8ecThOjxY+rVr1EAZpgAecdLe0PJcRzCIs7BoExJRh4RGiWNgSMnKKKuqaXgaSmFAA1vqskujmwYSRRcVkwIUlFSW0DIxpmUxKJgAUjjpQYDCY0ERN2NKSOnAAlERloZUTxZxwMDqcxKjSRDTTjkkAxBpEnTA+qsB9A3AAvrGyCspqGnUZRFAQnI2SwYeDqAD00iGTP5THQ+VfpNjoCgeEPtFvmDwe9ISDxkCIThcCAADQgXidaD0ZCgaScbhsAAK+IQOJQ-TY0gAnjj0QAjYxgDIzADKPGkYHSAHNkDBOIN0XAlPT3Hl0AAZaRQbk6aTcuAAMQejRgnRlyBA0j0EDRIBoMCUkgA6nR4PQOWA4KyyZhOtg7dTNWA5Hr0vRzDAicZuY1kI5+h70QAreguABCTJZMFZlwl6Tg-sDcBDYdZPJ8AEUdBB4EnJEHNPiPZxNfTpKLJHqeJx0jBjZh0LRkAAOAAM6JrEA9xuMPE1NbgJewifRAEcc-BvbxyVr6PooHB3O49dMJ5hpt75X6kAGCymQB6lJg+QKD-QM3Bs7nE7vk+iYBWG02aMgAEwP4yYOrcgDCECUHcQCHABWPUdA9AAVCtyT3QtsEGABJKA8lgVkwFrHgYAAQRQ1kYGpHx8w9Y5jiAA) and followed the warnings:

```
<div>
  {this.showdropdown && (
    <div className="popout-wrapper content-popout fixed-popout left show">
      <div className="popout-link-holder">
        {this.links.map(function (value) {
          return (
            <a href="#" title={value} className="link normal">
              value
            </a>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
</div
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.map`. Inside `.map` you are only rendering an element, so you need to use the `()` parenthesis instead of `{}`

```
{this.links.map((value) => (
    <a href="#" title={value} className="link normal">{value}</a>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is not far from correct. However there are two distinct ways of doing this.

1. You can try what some answers suggested which is called an `implicit return` as follows;

```
<div>
  {this.showdropdown && (
    <div className="popout-wrapper content-popout fixed-popout left show">
      <div className="popout-link-holder">
        {this.links.map((value) => (<a href="#" title={value} className="link normal"> {value} </a>))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

2. Or on your own shared example you can perform with regular return in brackets;

```
<div>
  {this.showdropdown ? (
    <div className="popout-wrapper content-popout fixed-popout left show">
      <div className="popout-link-holder">
        {this.links.forEach(function (value) {
          return (
            <a href="#" title={value} className="link normal">
              value
            </a>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null}
</div>;
```

The idea here is that if you use a function body with curly braces `{}` you need to return your JSX expression in brackets `()`.
If not, you can do an implicit return as mentioned in 1 as

```
(value) => (<div>{value}</div>)
```

Note: Should not be considered as 100% working examples. Since I have not run these against the compiler.